# Долгая загрузка мобильной версии сайта на Tilda

Tags: cms, веб-сайт, оптимизация-сайтов, tilda

Сайт разработан на Tilda, оптимизировано все что можно оптимизировать, кода JS минимум, контента немного. Очень долгая загрузка сайта на мобильной версии - около 10-12 секунд. При загрузке даже прелоадер зависает на несколько секунд.
Прочитаны все инструкции самой Tilda, тех. поддержка дает стандартные отписки, помощи никакой.
Куда еще можно посмотреть? Может ли как-то влиять хостинг, на котором зареган домен (timeweb)? Был перенос доменного имени в Tilda оттуда, плюс на нем есть почта.

Comment: *"оптимизировано все что можно"* - ¿вы это серьезно? Tilda - это же вроде кривенький конструктор сайтов, где на оптимизацию положен такой болт, что сделать с этим что-то уже невозможно.

Comment: Это в принципе первый сайт, уже понятно что проще было бы написать, но сейчас что-то сделать надо, т.к. этот точно останется на тильде. Плохой опыт - тоже опыт. Есть примеры где также долго грузятся, но и есть примеры на той же тильде, где они летают, причем по всей странице море контента, видео, фотки, фоны. Как у них так получается? Тут уже сжато все до минимума, а грузится как малолитражка.

Answer (score 1):

Самым правильным советом будет  - отказаться от использования конструктора. Хорошо работающие сайты не создают на конструкторах. Это просто лендинги для привлечения трафика которые живут месяц - два.
Если вы нацелены на развитие, то забудьте про `Tilda` / `Wix` / `Elementor` ... оптимизировать их изначально невозможно, они про зарабатывание денег и быструю реализацию.
Конструктор это идеальный вариант если у вас нет времени на разработку и ваш бюджет 200$

Для подтверждения моей мысли, разверните абсолютно пустую болванки с минимумом настроек, и оцените сколько лишнего с собой потянет сайт на конструкторе.